# Permission denied to call DownloadManager->addCompletedDownload method

Tags: android, download

I want to sent a notification to DownloadManager when my application has finished a download.

I have found a method in DownloadManager called [addCompletedDownload](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

So I added the following uses-permissions to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

and set activity “android:exported="true"”

But this method does not work.

Here is the log:

> ```
> W/ActivityManager(238): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10026
> W/ActivityManager(238): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { 
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED dat=file:///mnt/sdcard flg=0x10 } from
>   com.skymobi.browser (pid=19850, uid=10134) is not exported from uid 10026 due to
>   receiver com.android.providers.downloads/com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadReceiver
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add this in manifest too :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```